# Custom tab on content pages

Tags: umbraco7

I am looking for documentation to add custom tab on content pages.
I am creating a package, which will add this tab when get installed in Umbraco.
[image]
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developing-packages/90293-custom-tab-on-content-pages

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a document type in your package that includes your `Custom Tab` and then use `ContentTypeService` to get all Content types which you want to display this tab and call `.AddContentType(IContentTypeComposition contentType)` method for each of them.

you can find more details here [Add Content Type Method](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/models/contenttype#addcontenttype-icontenttypecomposition-contenttype)